# Directory created from command line not appearing in Nautilus

Tags: 12.04, nautilus

I created a directory from the command line using `mkdir` but it does not show in the parent directory in Nautilus. I can navigate to the created directory in Nautilus if I enter the full path. Nautilus even auto-completes the directory name as I type it.

How can I make Nautilus show the new directory?

My Nautilus version is 3.4.2 running on Ubuntu 12.04 Precise Pangolin.

Comment: Does the directory name you created start with a `.` If not what is the directory name?

Comment: The name is "GrantProposal". Ctrl+R solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, it turned out to be what I think is a caching problem. The parent directory was already open in Nautilus when I did the `mkdir`. When the new directory did not appear, I restarted Nautilus and navigated to the parent directory but the new directory was still missing. After posting the question, I did a `Ctrl+R` in the parent directory and the new directory appeared.